# Hibernate query cache LazyInitializationException

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data

I have L2 and query cache enabled and I face a strange problem when I have a query that is cached. All of the relationships in the entities are lazy initialised. Here is an example of an entity I'm querying:

```
@Entity
@Cache(usage = READ_WRITE)
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Accessors
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id", callSuper = false)
public class TestEntity {

  /** The Constant serialVersionUID. */
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @Column(updatable = false)
  private Long id;

  @OneToOne(cascade = ALL, fetch = LAZY)
  private AnotherTestEntity anotherTestEntity;

}

@Entity
@Cache(usage = READ_WRITE)
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Accessors
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id", callSuper = false)
public class AnotherTestEntity {

  /** The Constant serialVersionUID. */
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @Column(updatable = false)
  private Long id;

  @Column
  private String property;

}
```

When I execute a query that is not cached:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public TestEntity findTestEntity() {
  TestEntity testEntity = testEntityRepository.findOne(1);
  testEntity.getAnotherTestEntity().getProperty(); 

  return testEntity;
}
```

First time I invoke this method it query the database and adds the entity in the L2 cache. The second time I invoke it it loads the entity from the L2 cache and it still works fine.

The problem comes when I invoke a query that is cached. Here is an example:

```
@Repository
public interface TestEntityRepository {

  @Cachable(cacheNames = "testQuery")
  TestEntity findOne(Long id);
}
```

I will use the same method:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public TestEntity findTestEntity() {
  TestEntity testEntity = testEntityRepository.findOne(1);
  testEntity.getAnotherTestEntity().getProperty(); 

  return testEntity;
}
```

When I invoke it for the first time it still works fine- loads the data from the database. The problem comes with the second invocation, when it uses the query cache. This exception is thrown when I access the lazy initialized relation:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

I can see that the lazy initialized entity's session is null but I can't figure out why this is happening. As we know the query cache contains only ids of the entities associated with that query, then it goes and retrieves them from L2(reference: https://dzone.com/articles/pitfalls-hibernate-second-0). So I can't understand why the first example(without the query cache) is working fine and the second one is behaving so weirdly. Can someone explain and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

So I just dived into this problem and it just turns out that Spring cache abstraction can't be used with hibernate lazy loading proxy. Spring provides you an abstraction and they don't know about hibernate and hazelcast. Then hazelcast provides their implementation to work with spring. So when a method annotated with @Cachable is called Spring aspect checks the cache(using the provided CacheManager- in this case HazelcastCacheManager) and retrieves what is in the cache. The problem here is that the session in hibernate proxy is transient(and this is absolutely normal to be that way) so we retrieve from the cache an entity without the hibernate session and as spring doesn't want to couple with hibernate, the session is not set. And then we receive LazyInitializationException. But in the end of the day this is a very common problem and it's strange that there isn't a solution for it by spring. The thing that works is using hibernate query cache which has some other drawbacks using hazelcast.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a bug, but to be sure, you need to replicate it against the latest Hibernate ORM using [this test case template](http://in.relation.to/2018/06/04/best-way-write-hibernate-orm-issue-test-case/).

If you cannot reproduce it, it means the issue was either fixed and you need to upgrade Hibernate or the issue originates in Spring, not Hibernate.